# Android getAbsolutePath() not returning full path

Tags: android, android-file

I create a file and save an image to it using the following code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        return image;

    }
```

When I use `image.getAbsolutePath();`, I get somwthing like this:

`/data/data/co.za.package.app/files/filename.jpg`

The actual path of the image is:

`/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/co.za.package.app/files/filename.jpg`

Why is `getAbsolutePath()` returning the wrong path? I hardcoded the above `String` and my image displayed fine. Do any of you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The actual path of the image is

You may have a file there, but that is not the `File` that you are setting up in the code. Try `getExternalFilesDir(null)` instead of `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I want to save to image in the app internal directory and then retrieve it afterwards.