# How to find out if the image from the gallery was taken in portrait or landscape from camera

Tags: android, exif

- I have a image in gallery which was taken from camera
- I am trying to find out if the image is `portrait` or `landscape`

**I have the path obtained from below [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/1083093) as**

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181110_211757.jpg
```

Then i am using the [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface) to find the orientation:

```
 public static void getCameraPhotoOrientation(Activity activity, String imagePath) {



        String path =getPath(activity,imagePath);


        try {
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(path);
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    Timber.d("Type-1");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    Timber.d("Type-2");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    Timber.d("Type-3");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                    Timber.d("Type-4");
                    break;

            }
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I always get orientation as `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED`

---

How to resolve this

Comment: Get image width and height, if height > width then it is portrait, if width > height then it is landscape, and height = width, square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a image in gallery which was taken from camera

There is no way for a developer to guarantee that any particular image came from a camera app, unless the developer is the author of that camera app.

> I am trying to find out if the image is portrait or landscape

There is no requirement for an image to be either portrait or landscape. For example, the camera app might crop its photos to be circular or square.

> I have the path obtained from below code

That code will fail for lots of `Uri` values on lots of devices. If you want to use `ExifInterface` for a `Uri`, use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, then pass that `InputStream` to [this `ExifInterface` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)).

> I always get orientation as ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED

Images do not have to have EXIF headers, let alone `ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION`.

If that tag does not exist, you could examine the width and height of the image and make a guess:

- If the width is greater than the height, it might be landscape
- If the height is greater than the width, it might be portrait

This will fail for square images, and this will fail for cropped images (e.g., the photo was taken portrait, but the user cropped it such that the width is now greater than the height).

The best solution is to change your app to not care whether the image is portrait or landscape. The next-best solution is to ask the user how they want to handle the image, where perhaps you use the above algorithm to set the default option.

Comment: I have been reading your answers from a very long time now and wanted to really thank you , you write very detailed and brilliant answers . Could you please help me with my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53241140/firebase-job-dispatcher-not-scheduling-jobs-on-oreo-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Try it by changing path accessing process like below

```
File imFile = new File(imagePath);
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

this will explain [Android getAbsolutePath() not returning full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237007/android-getabsolutepath-not-returning-full-path) it